# Getting an error while unserializing data base array with php

Tags: php

Hi i have the following serialized PHP array stored in my mySQL database:

```
        a:2:{s:6:"access";a:116:{i:0;s:17:"catalog
/attribute";i:1;s:23:"catalog/attribute_group";i:2;s:16:"catalog/category";i:3;s
:16:"catalog/download";i:4;s:19:"catalog/information";i:5;s:20:"catalog/manufact
urer";i:6;s:14:"catalog/option";i:7;s:15:"catalog/product";i:8;s:14:"catalog/rev
iew";i:9;s:18:"common/filemanager";i:10;s:13:"design/banner";i:11;s:13:"design/l
ayout";i:12;s:14:"extension/feed";i:13;s:16:"extension/module";i:14;s:17:"extens
ion/payment";i:15;s:18:"extension/shipping";i:16;s:15:"extension/total";i:17;s:1
6:"feed/google_base";i:18;s:19:"feed/google_sitemap";i:19;s:20:"localisation/cou
ntry";i:20;s:21:"localisation/currency";i:21;s:21:"localisation/geo_zone";i:22;s
:21:"localisation/language";i:23;s:25:"localisation/length_class";i:24;s:25:"loc
alisation/order_status";i:25;s:26:"localisation/return_action";i:26;s:26:"locali
sation/return_reason";i:27;s:26:"localisation/return_status";i:28;s:25:"localisa
tion/stock_status";i:29;s:22:"localisation/tax_class";i:30;s:21:"localisation/ta
x_rate";i:31;s:25:"localisation/weight_class";i:32;s:17:"localisation/zone";i:33
;s:14:"module/account";i:34;s:16:"module/affiliate";i:35;s:13:"module/banner";i:
36;s:17:"module/bestseller";i:37;s:15:"module/carousel";i:38;s:15:"module/catego
ry";i:39;s:15:"module/featured";i:40;s:18:"module/google_talk";i:41;s:18:"module
/information";i:42;s:13:"module/latest";i:43;s:16:"module/slideshow";i:44;s:14:"
module/special";i:45;s:12:"module/store";i:46;s:14:"module/welcome";i:47;s:16:"p
ayment/alertpay";i:48;s:24:"payment/authorizenet_aim";i:49;s:21:"payment/bank_tr
ansfer";i:50;s:14:"payment/cheque";i:51;s:11:"payment/cod";i:52;s:21:"payment/fr
ee_checkout";i:53;s:14:"payment/liqpay";i:54;s:20:"payment/moneybookers";i:55;s:
14:"payment/nochex";i:56;s:15:"payment/paymate";i:57;s:16:"payment/paypoint";i:5
8;s:26:"payment/perpetual_payments";i:59;s:14:"payment/pp_pro";i:60;s:17:"paymen
t/pp_pro_uk";i:61;s:19:"payment/pp_standard";i:62;s:15:"payment/sagepay";i:63;s:
22:"payment/sagepay_direct";i:64;s:18:"payment/sagepay_us";i:65;s:19:"payment/tw
ocheckout";i:66;s:28:"payment/web_payment_software";i:67;s:16:"payment/worldpay"
;i:68;s:27:"report/affiliate_commission";i:69;s:22:"report/customer_credit";i:70
;s:21:"report/customer_order";i:71;s:22:"report/customer_reward";i:72;s:24:"repo
rt/product_purchased";i:73;s:21:"report/product_viewed";i:74;s:18:"report/sale_c
oupon";i:75;s:17:"report/sale_order";i:76;s:18:"report/sale_return";i:77;s:20:"r
eport/sale_shipping";i:78;s:15:"report/sale_tax";i:79;s:14:"sale/affiliate";i:80
;s:12:"sale/contact";i:81;s:11:"sale/coupon";i:82;s:13:"sale/customer";i:83;s:19
:"sale/customer_group";i:84;s:10:"sale/order";i:85;s:11:"sale/return";i:86;s:12:
"sale/voucher";i:87;s:18:"sale/voucher_theme";i:88;s:15:"setting/setting";i:89;s
:13:"setting/store";i:90;s:17:"shipping/citylink";i:91;s:13:"shipping/flat";i:92
;s:13:"shipping/free";i:93;s:13:"shipping/item";i:94;s:23:"shipping/parcelforce_
48";i:95;s:15:"shipping/pickup";i:96;s:19:"shipping/royal_mail";i:97;s:12:"shipp
ing/ups";i:98;s:13:"shipping/usps";i:99;s:15:"shipping/weight";i:100;s:11:"tool/
backup";i:101;s:14:"tool/error_log";i:102;s:12:"total/coupon";i:103;s:12:"total/
credit";i:104;s:14:"total/handling";i:105;s:19:"total/low_order_fee";i:106;s:12:
"total/reward";i:107;s:14:"total/shipping";i:108;s:15:"total/sub_total";i:109;s:
9:"total/tax";i:110;s:11:"total/total";i:111;s:13:"total/voucher";i:112;s:9:"use
r/user";i:113;s:20:"user/user_permission";i:114;s:15:"shipping/pickup";i:115;s:
7:"sale/ad";}s:6:"modify";a:116:{i:0;s:17:"catalog/attribute";i:1;s:23:"catalog/
attribute_group";i:2;s:16:"catalog/category";i:3;s:16:"catalog/download";i:4;s:19:
"catalog/information";i:5;s:20:"catalog/manufacturer";i:6;s:14:"catalog/option";i:
7;s:15:"catalog/product";i:8;s:14:"catalog/review";i:9;s:18:"common/filemanager";
i:10;s:13:"design/banner";i:11;s:13:"design/layout";i:12;s:14:"extension/feed";i:
13;s:16:"extension/module";i:14;s:17:"extension/payment";i:15;s:18:"extension/
shipping";i:16;s:15:"extension/total";i:17;s:16:"feed/google_base";i:18;s:19:
"feed/google_sitemap";i:19;s:20:"localisation/country";i:20;s:21:"localisation/
currency";i:21;s:21:"localisation/geo_zone";i:22;s:21:"localisation/language";
i:23;s:25:"localisation/length_class";i:24;s:25:"localisation/order_status";i:
25;s:26:"localisation/return_action";i:26;s:26:"localisation/return_reason";i:27;
s:26:"localisation/return_status";i:28;s:25:"localisation/stock_status";i:29;s:22:
"localisation/tax_class";i:30;s:21:"localisation/tax_rate";i:31;s:25:"localisation/
weight_class";i:32;s:17:"localisation/zone";i:33;s:14:"module/account";i:34;s:16:
"module/affiliate";i:35;s:13:"module/banner";i:36;s:17:"module/bestseller";i:37;s:
15:"module/carousel";i:38;s:15:"module/category";i:39;s:15:"module/featured";i:40;
s:18:"module/google_talk";i:41;s:18:"module/information";i:42;s:13:"module/latest";
i:43;s:16:"module/slideshow";i:44;s:14:"module/special";i:45;s:12:"module/store";i:
46;s:14:"module/welcome";i:47;s:16:"payment/alertpay";i:48;s:24:"payment/authoriz
enet_aim";i:49;s:21:"payment/bank_transfer";i:50;s:14:"payment/cheque";i:51;s:11:
"payment/cod";i:52;s:21:"payment/free_checkout";i:53;s:14:"payment/liqpay";i:54;
s:20:"payment/moneybookers";i:55;s:14:"payment/nochex";i:56;s:15:"payment/paymat
e";i:57;s:16:"payment/paypoint";i:58;s:26:"payment/perpetual_payments";i:59;s:14:
"payment/pp_pro";i:60;s:17:"payment/pp_pro_uk";i:61;s:19:"payment/pp_standard";i:
62;s:15:"payment/sagepay";i:63;s:22:"payment/sagepay_direct";i:64;s:18:"payment/
sagepay_us";i:65;s:19:"payment/twocheckout";i:66;s:28:"payment/web_payment_softw
are";i:67;s:16:"payment/worldpay";i:68;s:27:"report/affiliate_commission";i:69;s
:22:"report/customer_credit";i:70;s:21:"report/customer_order";i:71;s:22:"report
/customer_reward";i:72;s:24:"report/product_purchased";i:73;s:21:"report/produc
t_viewed";i:74;s:18:"report/sale_coupon";i:75;s:17:"report/sale_order";i:76;s:18
:"report/sale_return";i:77;s:20:"report/sale_shipping";i:78;s:15:"report/sale_ta
x";i:79;s:14:"sale/affiliate";i:80;s:12:"sale/contact";i:81;s:11:"sale/coupon";i
:82;s:13:"sale/customer";i:83;s:19:"sale/customer_group";i:84;s:10:"sale/order";
i:85;s:11:"sale/return";i:86;s:12:"sale/voucher";i:87;s:18:"sale/voucher_theme";
i:88;s:15:"setting/setting";i:89;s:13:"setting/store";i:90;s:17:"shipping/cityli
nk";i:91;s:13:"shipping/flat";i:92;s:13:"shipping/free";i:93;s:13:"shipping/item"
;i:94;s:23:"shipping/parcelforce_48";i:95;s:15:"shipping/pickup";i:96;s:19:"ship
ping/royal_mail";i:97;s:12:"shipping/ups";i:98;s:13:"shipping/usps";i:99;s:15:"sh
ipping/weight";i:100;s:11:"tool/backup";i:101;s:14:"tool/error_log";i:102;s:12:"t
otal/coupon";i:103;s:12:"total/credit";i:104;s:14:"total/handling";i:105;s:19:"to
tal/low_order_fee";i:106;s:12:"total/reward";i:107;s:14:"total/shipping";i:108;s:  15:"total/sub_total";i:109;s:9:"total/tax";i:110;s:11:"total/total";i:111;s:13:"
total/voucher";i:112;s:9:"user/user";i:113;s:20:"user/user_permission";i:114;s:1
5:"shipping/pickup";i:115;s:7:"sale/ad";}}
```

now i am unserializing this array using the fallowing steps:

```
            $user_group_query = $this->db->query("SELECT permission FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user_group WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_query->row['user_group_id'] . "'");

            $permissions = unserialize($user_group_query->row['permission']);
```

but i am getting the error saying:

```
    Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 7081 bytes in D:\wamp\www\UI\system\library\user.php on line 23
```

why i am getting this error???
if anyone faced the similar problem plese help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a quick guess that whitespace found it's way into the string, add a trim() before to the serialized string before trying to unserialize it.